Blazor + select2 + @bind
When I use select 2 I can't get the value, it always returns null.
Can you help me? I've already tried doing @bind, @onchange and nothing works.
My Code :
<select class="form-select" data-control="select2" data-placeholder="Select an option" 
      id="I18NCodeSelect" data-dropdown-parent="#kt_modal_add_form"
      @bind="_newModel.CodeI18NId">
<option value="">Select I18N Code</option>
 @if (i18nCodes != null && i18nCodes.Any())
      { 
        @foreach (var i18nCode in i18nCodes)
           {
  <option value="@i18nCode.Id" selected="@(_selectedLanguage == i18nCode.Code)">
@i18nCode.Code </option>
           }
       }
   else
      {
          <option value="" disabled>Loading languages...</option>
      }
</select>
<label for="_selectedCodeI18NResponse">Language</label>
</div>
<p>You selected: @_newModel.CodeI18NId</p>
</div>

This return every time null with using select2 You selected: @_newModel.CodeI18NId
I tried to use @onchange, @bind and if i use select2 the valor here You selected: @_newModel.CodeI18NId it's null everytime.

What is Select2?

When i put this data-control="select2"

So you are using a component library?  Also what version of Net?  What Blazor template did you deploy? What interactivity [Server/WASM/Auto]?  Interactivity Location [Global or Per Page/Component]?  All are pertinent to an answer.

Hello again ,
My version of .net is 8.0 and i'm using Metronic theme.
I'm getting the values ​​through an api.
The issue here is that if I don't use data-control="select2" it can capture the values. I've read that it has to do with the way select2 works but I haven't been able to resolve it. I added this Select-2 because i want a search on dropdown, and this theme use select-2

I don't think you should use a javascript library like select-2 for manipulating the select-object when running Blazor. From what I remember, select-2 uses javascript to modify the html-code, which is bad, because Blazor does not know of this modification. Blazor needs to know what's happening in the UI/DOM of the browser, and any modification might cause unintended behaviour, such as this.
Have you tried looking into other components, such as MudBlazor's Autocomplete-field?
https://mudblazor.com/components/autocomplete#visual-playground
There's probably other standalone components you can use as well, without having to import the "whole" MudBlazor, but I think you should look at other solutions than select-2.
